# Algebraic Manipulation of a Separable Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(\sin (x)+x^2e^y-1) {\rm d} y/{\rm d}x=-y\cos (x)-2xe^y$$

I understand how to do these problems but I'm wondering how do I get the y variables on the left hand side and the x variables on the right hand side so that I can integrate.

Comment: Are you sure it is a separable equation? Have you learned exact equations? Looks to me that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not separable to my knowledge. This is an exact differential equation. In fact, it can be rewritten as:

$$(-ycos(x)-2xe^y)dx + (-sin(x)-x^2e^y+1)dy =0$$

$M = -ycos(x)-2xe^y$

$N = -sin(x)-x^2e^y+1$

\begin{cases} \ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}
   = -cosx - 2xe^y \\ \ \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} = -cosx - 2xe^y  \end{cases}

$\implies M_y = N_x$

$\implies$ There exists a $f(x,y) = c$ such that $f_x = M$ and $f_y = N$.

$f_x = -ycos(x)-2xe^y$
$\implies$
$f = -ysinx -x^2e^y + g(y)$

$f_y = -sin(x)-x^2e^y+1$
$\implies$
$f = -sinx -x^2e^y + g'(y) =-sin(x)-x^2e^y+1 $
$\implies$
$g'(y) = 1$
$\implies$
$g(y) = y + c_1$

Thus $f(x,y) = -sinx -x^2e^y + y = c_2$

Answer (score 1):

Your title says "separable equation", but are you sure this a separable equation?

You can try to check if this is an exact equation, which is an equation of the form 
$$M(x,y) + N(x,y)y' = 0$$
where
$$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} = M(x,y),\quad \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y} = N(x,y)$$
for some function $\psi(x,y)$.  For exact equations, the solution is given by $\psi(x,y) = c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(y\sin x+x^2e^y-y)=\sin x+x^2e^y-1
$$

$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(y\sin x+x^2e^y-y)=y\cos x+2xe^y
$$